# State of PWA and WKWebView on iOS 13

Tags: ios, webkit, progressive-web-apps, wkwebview

I googled about the question but couldn't find a clear answer. It seems Apple supported it once in iOS 11. But according the a [blog](https://webkit.org/blog/8090/workers-at-your-service/) post it's no longer supported in WKWebView. Can anyone confirm the latest status of the question? Thanks!

Comment: Are you asking about Progressive Web Apps, or Service Workers? The not the same thing.

Comment: @mattsven Thanks for the reply. Actually I'm asking about Service Workers because I want to develop an App with Ionic and Cordova and I want cache many server resources on client side to improve user experiences.